# Non Cyclic Subgroup of D12

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A bit stuck on this question: Let $G=D_{12}$=$({r^{i}s^j}:0\leq i \leq 5, 0 \leq j \leq 1)$ and $sr^{i}=r^{6-i}s$ Find a non-cyclic subgroup of $D_{12}$ of order 4. List the elements of the subgroup explicitly.

so far I understand that $D_{12}=({1,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,r^5,s,sr,sr^2,sr^3,sr^4,sr^5})$ and that I have to find four elements that satisfy the group axioms, what I don't understand is how to find them.

Any advice/hints would be appreciated (fairly new to group theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, we can interpret $D_{12}$ as the symmetry group of a regular hexagon. Then we see the symmetry group of a rectangle within this hexagon, which has the following elements:

- identity
- flip over some diagonal of the hexagon
- flip over a line perpendicularly bisecting said diagonal
- the composition of the preceding operations

Here is a picture to demonstrate this.

[image]

These correspond to elements $\{1,s,sr^3,r^3\}$ in your notation. I leave it to you to verify that these elements form the sole non-cyclic order-4 group, the Klein four-group.

Comment: Sorry don't understand why are we using a rectangle to look at the symmetry group of the hexagon?

Comment: @Reety It's just a visual aid. You may ignore this and just show that the elements I have given you are a group.

Comment: also how do I determine the elements of order 4? I understand that by lagranges theorem we have possible orders being 1,2,3,4,6,12 but don't understand how we actually obtain the elements within these subgroups so how would I know to obtain the elements in order 2?

Comment: @Reety As it turns out, the subgroup I gave you has _no_ elements of order 4. All the reflections $sr^n$ have order 2, all the non-trivial rotations $r^n$ have orders 2, 3 or 6 here.

Comment: is there a method to obtain the elements within the subgroup?

Comment: @Reety there's not really one systematic method; it's just guessing and checking, these kinds of problems.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!:)

Comment: @Reety I notice you don't accept answers; would you like to accept my answer? It will gain some reputation for you.

Comment: sorry I'm fairly new to the platform, I shall :)